# Install NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu without desktop environment

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome

Is desktop environment (e.g. gnome) necessary for the NVIDIA driver installation? I'm trying to install it on a terminal-only Ubuntu, and the driver can't detect the hardware.

Comment: Can't answer the question, but there is in general no need to install NVIDIA gfxy drivers if you are running a headless server.

Answer (score 0):

It should be unnecessary. At last I successfully installed the driver without desktop environment. However, I installed lightdm first--it may be essential or not.